# XML node is always null

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces

The following function does not return the value of the node that I want, which is "CompanyPolicyId". I have tried so many things and I still cannot get it to work. Anyone know what might be the issue?

```
 public void getpolicy(string rootURL, string policyNumber)
        {
            string basePolicyNumber = policyNumber.Remove(policyNumber.Length - 2);
            basePolicyNumber = basePolicyNumber + "00";

            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential();
                credentials.UserName = AppVars.Username;
                credentials.Password = AppVars.Password;
                client.Credentials = credentials;

                try
                {
                    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

                    doc.LoadXml(client.DownloadString(rootURL + basePolicyNumber));
                    XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
                    mgr.AddNamespace("zzzlocal", "http://com.zzz100.policy.data.local");

                    // Select the Identifier node with a 'name' attribute having an 'id' value
                    var node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/InsurancePolicy/Indentifiers/Identifier[@name='CompanyPolicyId']", mgr);
                    if (node != null && node.Attributes["value"] != null)
                    {
                        // Pick out the 'value' attribute's value
                        var val = node.Attributes["value"].Value;

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
```

Here's the XML document:

```
<InsurancePolicy xmlns:zzzlocal="com.zzz100.policy.data.local" schemaVersion="2.7" variant="multiterm">
<Identifiers>
<Identifier name="VendorPolicyId" value="AAAA"/>
<Identifier name="CompanyPolicyId" value="BBBB"/>
<Identifier name="QuoteNumber" value="CCCC"/>
<Identifier name="pxServerIndex" value="DDDD"/>
<Identifier name="PolicyID" value="EEEE"/>
</Identifiers>
</InsurancePolicy>
```

I've been trying to fix this problem for the last 6 hours. Honestly, this sucks.

Comment: have you stepped thru the code ..? try that and see where the NULL value shows up at..

Comment: it's null on this line: var node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/InsurancePolicy/Indentifiers/Identifier[@name='CompanyPolicyId']", mgr);

Comment: what would happen if you changede it to read something like this ..? //Identifier[@name='CompanyPolicyId']"

Comment: remove the http:// from the namespace in the namespacemanager

Comment: @DJKRAZE, now I got "Element, Name='Identifier'" for the node var.

Comment: @rene, I removed it and nothing changed. I need to get the value for CompanyPolicyId but the SELECTSINGLENODE is bringing back the value "Identifier"

Comment: I will post an example but you will need to refactor your code to reflect this working example

Comment: Which fixed the problem what I suggested earlier.. if so I will post it as my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this

```
//Identifier[@name='CompanyPolicyId']"
```

or a different approach below

```
XElement rootElement = XElement.Load(<url here>);
string targetValue =
  (string)rootElement.Elements("Identifier")
  .Single(e => (string)e.Attribute("name") == "CompanyPolicyId")
  .Attribute("value");
```

This assumes that you want to be able to target one of the Identifier nodes by name, and that you are sure that there will be an element WITH that name.  If that is not true, then the .Single call will throw an Exception if that node is not found.

If you needed to use credentials and wanted to use a WebClient, then you could use the following:
(Note, I have done no exception handling, checking for stream availability, or otherwise disposed/closed the streams, just an example of how to get it to "work")

```
string uri = "> url here! <";
System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wc.OpenRead(uri));
string xml = sr.ReadToEnd();
XElement rootElement = XElement.Parse(xml);
string targetValue =
  (string)rootElement.Elements("Identifier")
  .Single(e => (string)e.Attribute("name") == "CompanyPolicyId")
  .Attribute("value");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is simpler version

```
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        XElement root = XElement.Load(@"C:\1.xml");
        XElement identifier = GetIdentifierByName(root, "CompanyPolicyId");
        if (identifier == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(identifier.Attribute("value"));
    }

    private static XElement GetIdentifierByName(XContainer root, string name)
    {
        return root.Descendants()
            .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Identifier")
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Attribute("name").Value == name);
    }
}
```

Console output is `BBBB`